# unity3d webgl mute the sound when tab or browser inactive

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know a proper way to mute the sound in the game when tab or browser is inactive?

I've tried to do this by [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jt6cm9ng/)(by JS libraries) way

```
var hidden, visibilityChange;
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "hidden";
    visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "mozHidden";
    visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "msHidden";
    visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "webkitHidden";
    visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);

function handleVisibilityChange() {
    $("video").prop('muted', document[hidden]);
}
```

but its not work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but you probably could use [`OnApplicationFocus`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html) and [`OnApplicationPause`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html) on a controller component within Unity.

It could then enable and disable all sound by simply set [`AudioListener.pause`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener-pause.html) or alternatively the [`AudioListener.volume`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener-volume.html) accordingly

```
public class FocusSoundController : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)
    {
        Silence(!hasFocus);
    }

    void OnApplicationPause(bool isPaused)
    {
        Silence(isPaused);
    }

    private void Silence(bool silence)
    {
        AudioListener.pause = silence;
        // Or / And
        AudioListener.volume = silence ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While using OnApplicationFocus will work it will also mute things if they switch to another window but you can still see the browser which may not be what you want.

If you go to the bottom of the thread below you'll see a post by someone from Unity and they give an example that uses the visibility change similar to what's in the original post but also has the Unity C# side that you'll need to actually get it to work.  I didn't like hard coding the object name so I passed its gameObject.name when it calls the register function.  I'm not used to working with `jslib` plugins so initially, I didn't convert the pointer to a string in the `jslib` using Pointer_stringify(str).  If you do this you'll also want to set it to a local var or when an event triggers your string pointer could be anything.

[Pause and Tabbing Events](https://forum.unity.com/threads/onpause-events-for-webgl-builds.432775/)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the editor won’t like trying to run the code related to registerVisiblilityChangeEvent so I put a “#if UNITY_WEBGL && !UNITY_EDITOR” around that code.

Otherwise you’ll get a “EntryPointNotFoundException: registerVisibilityChangeEvent error.